# Accessing iCloud page in System Settings in macOS Ventura causes stalling, high CPU and ExtensionKit error 15

Tags: icloud, system-settings

Accessing System Settings > Internet Accounts > iCloud causes my Macbook Pro (running Ventura 13.3.1) to stall, high CPU, and everything going jumpy. Then an error message: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.extensionKit.errorDomain error 15.)"

[image]

Any ideas what might be causing this? Others online seem to have had the same error message but for different reasons.